# relatedEvents empty on eventAdd callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

Runnning a Vue3/Vite setup with Fullcalendar and a graphql/sequelize/mysql backend.

Tried to implement recurring events in my app today and wanted to leverage the eventAdd callback to use the relatedEvent prop.  **I expected** to get all my recurring events returned in this array so that I could inject them into my database for persistence but it returns empty no matter how I approach the issue.

Created a simple hardcoded recurring event object in my  and call it via a simple <button @click> event.

```
function createRecurEvents() {
  const uuid = uuidv4()
  const newEvent = {
    id: '100',
    title: 'title',
    startTime: '10:00:00',
    endTime: '12:00:00',
    groupId: uuid,
    startRecur: '2023-11-28',
    endRecur: '2023-12-28',
    daysOfWeek: [2, 4],
    resourceIds: ['7383e073-055e-4458-8dcc-e0f7fc2d3c56'],
  }
  fullCalendar.value.getApi().addEvent(newEvent)
}
```

The recurring events is added fine to my calendar and then I try to read them by using eventAdd callback like this:

```
function handleEventAdd(addInfo: any) {
  console.log(addInfo)
}
```

The console logs my event with "event", "relatedEvent" and "revert" properties but relatedEvents remain empty even though my calendar has rendered lets say 10 events. The groupId is set to all events. Tried with or without id and I have also tried with or without event sources, multiple event sources and specified my eventsource in addEvent function.

console.log:

[image]

**I expected** to get all my recurring events returned in this array (relatedEvents)

Comment: I reproduced this problem using the latest vanilla fullCalendar - see https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJrZQgm . I agree this doesn't seem to be doing what is stated in the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventAdd . I think you need to report this as a bug to the fullCalendar team - see https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs for details.

Comment: Thanks, it is now reported and confirmed as a bug. https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/7460